# Perl oneliner might be a runaway multi-line ++ message

Tags: perl

I am trying to reformat the date for MySQL. This Perl one-liner give me below error message.

I would like understand why it's giving this error message.

```
echo 'Dec 2 04:08:40 EST 2012' | perl -lane ' my @abbr = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
                ( $amon, $mday, $hour,$tz, $year) =split('\s+',$_);
                for (my $i = 0; $i < @abbr; $i++) {
                next unless $abbr[$i] =~ /^$amon/;
                $mon=$i;
                }
                $mon++;
                print  "$year-$mon-$mday $hour";

            '
```

**Error Message**

```
syntax error at -e line 3, near ") {"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line ++ string starting on line 2)
syntax error at -e line 9, near ";}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Doesn't the syntax highlighting in your post help you spot at least one of the problems? Put all that in a script, there's no point in trying to do that on the command line.

Comment: I used this in part of shell scirpt, in VIM it didn't show it

Comment: Using 10 lines (including a blank line) for a 'one-liner' seems like a contradiction in terms.  In Perl, you can choose which character(s) to use for 'single quotes', so write:  `split(q{\s+}, $_);` to avoid having single quotes in your Perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have tried to embed single quotes within a single-quoted string. You could escape them, but `split` will split `$_` on whitespace by default.

Here is a solution, but as Mat says this is a program, not a one-liner. Put it in a file.

```
echo 'Dec 2 04:08:40 EST 2012' | perl -lane '
@abbr = qw( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec );
($amon, $mday, $hour, $tz, $year) = split;
for my $i (0..$#abbr) {
  next unless $abbr[$i] =~ /^$amon/;
  $mon=$i;
}
$mon++;
print  "$year-$mon-$mday $hour";'
```

Comment: In the shell you technically _can't_ escape single quotes inside of single quotes. There are work-arounds.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I overlooked single qutoe. converted script into online to use with-in the shell script.

Comment: @jordanm `'\''` being the most foolproof that I know of.

Comment: @hobbs, right, and you are actually closing the single quotes before escaping.